# takeWhile: also need first element failed the condition in scala

Tags: scala

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).takeWhile(i=>i<5) 
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

What if I also need to include 5 in the result?

Comment: You could find the length of the result, and then index your source list to get the next one. `val v = list.takeWhile(_ < 5); v ++ list(v.length)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the function that you will be using is more complicated than the taking first 5 elements then,

You can do

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
res5: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

scala> res5.takeWhile(_<5) ++ res5.dropWhile(_<5).take(1)
res7: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Also

```
scala> res5.span(_<5)
res8: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1, 2, 3, 4),List(5, 6, 7))
scala> res8._1 ++ res8._2.take(1)
res10: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Also

```
scala> res5.take(res5.segmentLength(_<5, 0) + 1)
res17: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> res5.take(res5.indexWhere(_>5))
res18: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

If this is not a parallelized computation and you won't be using the parallel collections:

```
var last = myList.head
val rem = myList.takeWhile{ x=>
  last = x
  x < 5
}

last :: rem
```

anonymous function forming a closure around the solution you want.

**Previous Answer**

I'd settle for the far less complicated:

```
.takeWhile(_ <= 5)
```

wherein you're just using the less than or equal operator.

Comment: From the question title, I'd assume that the example is only indicative, which means that your solution would be too specific

Comment: It fails on different data. `List(2,4,6,8)` would return only the first two items.

Comment: @pagoda_5b you're right. I did not read the title, only the question.

Answer (score -1):

List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).takeWhile(_ <= 5)

This is best optimal solution for it

Comment: How does this differ from wheaties answer?

Comment: It only works for the given data set. How about a source list of `List(2, 4, 6, 8)`?